# Real time plotting using Matplotlib. X axis getting over-written

Tags: python, matplotlib, real-time

[image: update code]I'm plotting real-time data using parsed data from a file that is being repeatedly opened. The plotting works great until the X axis (time) runs out a room. I'm trying to figure out a way to advance to the next element and shift the time values to the left. Code and screenshot included here.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import datetime
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

x = []
y = []
rssi_val = []

def animate(i):
    with open('stats.txt', 'r') as searchfile:
#        time = (searchfile.read(5))
        time = (searchfile.read(8))
        for line in searchfile:
            if 'agrCtlRSSI:' in line:
                rssi_val = line[16:20]
                y.append(rssi_val)
                x.append(time[-1])


    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x,y)
    next(x)
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('RSSI')
    plt.title('Real time signal strength seen by client X')
    plt.tight_layout()

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=5000)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just rotate the labels,

```py
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_rotation(90)
```

or

```py
ax.tick_params('x', labelrotation=90)
```

**before** calling `plt.plot()`.

Comment: Thanks again William. However, when I add that just above plt.plot(x,y) I get "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_xticklabels'. I'm thinking it's because I didn't define something correctly (?).

Comment: Preface it with `ax=plt.gca()` or use `plt.gca().get_xticklabels()`

Comment: I tried the first suggestion, followed by the second and unfortunately the time values are still getting squeezed. Entire snippet in updated image above.

Comment: @wiwinut Needs to be after `plt.plot()`

Comment: You have come to my rescue once again. Thank you so much!